memset() vs. std::fill()
Can anyone tell me the difference between memset() and std::fill() in c++?
I am quite confused why my code doesn't work with memset() but does with std::fill().
I am making a Sieve of Eratosthenes like usual and I was expecting a series of 1s and 0s for my sieve
but it keeps giving me this number '72340172838076673'
Here is my code :
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long s[2000009],a[1000009],i,j,n;
void seive(int N) {
    j = 1;
    memset(s,1,sizeof(s));
    s[0] = 0;
    s[1] = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(N); i++) {
        if(s[i] == 1)
            for(int j = i * i; j <= N; j += i) {
                s[j] = 0;
            }
    }
}

int main () {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);
    cin>>n;
    seive(2e6);
    for (i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
       cin>>a[i];
       cout<<s[a[i]]<<'\n';
    }
}


Basic C++" ehr no... In C++ you would (almost never) use ::memset and ::fill period.  You wouldn't even global variables (let alone statically sized arrays).  Have a look at std::array/std::fill. Or just use one of the apprioate constructors of std::vector. E.g. to make an array filled with all zeroes std::array<int,10> values{}; is enough

Side note using an array  long long is complete waste of space to store primes, and you can calculate a table with all primes at compile time. e.g. : https://onlinegdb.com/ryu3nT-LPb / https://godbolt.org/z/39e89obTT

The long long value of 72340172838076673 is 0x0101010101010101.

don't use using namespace std and never use #include <bits/stdc++.h>. long long s[2000009],a[1000009],i,j,n; has lots of issues and will never pass code review in any company: global variables, static arrays, multiple variables in the same line, code formatting...

The documentation for std::fill() says:

Assigns val to all the elements in the range [first,last)."

This means that std::fill will work with any data type.
On the other hand, the documentation for memset() says:

Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).".

This means that memset() will only work with bytes. If your array of values is not an array of bytes, or if the value to fill with is not a byte, they will still both be interpreted as bytes, which means that you are highly unlikely to get anything meaningful.

Good explanation, +1. To emphasize the point: In this case memset will surely not work, assuming the OP would like the long long array elements to be initialized to 1. Instead it will set each byte to 1 which will yield some very high long long value.

@wohlstad thanks.  Call it a little perversion of mine if you wish, but I like to give answers that are, if possible, more general than the specific narrow question asked.

If applied on objects of none-trivial types, mem functions - including std::memset - most often result in UB. But std::fill, std::copy and std::move(there's on overload that moves ranges, just like copy), always do the trick.
